# PayPal ipn notify_url on different sites

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, sites

I'm planning to implement paypal ipn on multiple sites. But since on
Paypal Payment preferences we can specify only ONE url I must find
an alternative way.

First way is to implement a _POST broadcast (specify a main ipn url for
all sites and redirect _POST variables to the correct site's ipn depending
on a certain condition);

Second way is to specify a different notify_url on each site's form like:
On Site1.com

```
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://site1.com/ipn.php"/>
```

On Site2.com

```
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://site2.com/ipn.php"/>
```

I read that if I specify a notify_url on the paypal form then it will
overwrite the ipn url saved on paypal account settings.
Is that correct?
 Is that a reliable way?
**strong text**

Lets say the ipn url on my paypal settings is
http://mypersonalwebsite.com/ipn.php
Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, specifying notify_url in the payment will override any value set in the PayPal account profile.

The only time this wouldn't work out for you is if you're working with subscriptions/recurring payments.  In that case, the IPNs that are sent for the future payments that belong to the profile would go to the URL listed in the PayPal account.

Comment: Thank you Andrew for your answer!